# Facebook login using SDK 4

Tags: facebook, authentication, kohana

I'm trying to make Facebook login for my site. 
I have Facebook App, I've made AppId, Secred and it is shown facebook login but I can't set session. I'm using facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev and Kohana Framework. 
It doesn't show me session data. 
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: user_profile
Please how to do that?

This is my controller:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' ); 
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php' ); 
require_once( 'Facebook/src/Facebook/GraphLocation.php' ); 

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphObject as GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphLocation;

use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

class Controller_Membership extends Controller_App {


    public function before() {

        parent::before();


        $this->template->title = __('p | Membership');

        $this->template->active = 'membership';

    }

 public function action_fbLogin(){
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start();}



$app_id  = '99589535'; // My Facebook App ID
$app_secret  = '6be9bd69b1b2a4d2e3f3dd'; //secret
$required_scope     = 'public_profile, publish_actions, email'; 
$redirect_url  = 'mysite_url';  


Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id , $app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);


try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}
 catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
}



var_dump($this->session);
if ($session){ //if we have the FB session


   $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();
$user_profile = $response->getGraphObject();
var_dump($this->request);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($user_profile); 
    echo '</pre>';

}
else{


    $login_url = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => $required_scope ) );
    echo '<a href="'.$redirect_url.'">Login with Facebook</a>';
echo '<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" scope="publish_actions,public_profile,email" onlogin="javascript:CallAfterLogin();"></fb:login-button>';
}

   print_r($user_profile); 




}
```

This is my header file:

```html
<span id="status">

 <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" scope="publish_actions,public_profile,email" href="<?php echo URL::base()?>membership/fbLogin"></fb:login-button>

   
    </span>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pbombd-header-menu-buttons" href="<?php echo URL::base()?>membership/register">Sign Up</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you need to download sdk v4 and domain name according to whtatever you have passed while creating app in facebook

Answer (score 1):

You need to download Facebook sdk first

```
<?php

session_start();


require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;

use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookResponse;

use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;

use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;

use Facebook\GraphObject;


// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('your_app_id','your_secret_key');

// login helper with redirect_uri

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.yahoo.com/' );

try {

 $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {

  // When Facebook returns an error

} catch( Exception $ex ) {

  // When validation fails or other local issues

}

// see if we have a session

if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // graph api request for user data

  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );

  $response = $request->execute();

  // get response

  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();


  // print data

  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );

} else {

  // show login url

  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';

}
```

Comment: It's not working. I don't know where the problem is. I have downloaded sdk 4. Do you want to send my files to you? I've tried this for days...

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 from this link you can download fb sdk v4  and Facebook folder you can copy from that and keep where your php file resides

Comment: I have downloaded facebook sdk. I've tried many times, but I don'w know where I'm wrong. Would you like to see my project folder?